# How to make a reactive color scale in leaflet map

Tags: r, shiny, react-leaflet, shiny-reactivity, r-leaflet

Building a map in leaflet where color scale changes accordingly to the inputs.

```
server <- function(input, output){

      raio <- shiny::reactive({ as.data.frame(agrocorrigidoMGBA %>% 
                                                dplyr::select(lat, lon, input$cultivoTB1, ANO, MUNICIPIO, ESTADO) %>% 
                                                dplyr::filter(ANO == input$anoTB1pizza, ESTADO == "MG"))
      })
```

The raio is a dataframe where the column 1 to 6 is latitude, longitude, **input cultivoTB1**, etc. This last one is a numeric column. Then, I try to build a **pal** based on the **input cultivoTB1**:

```
 pal <- reactive({
        leaflet::colorNumeric(
          palette = "Blues",
          domain = raio()[, 3]
        )
      })
```

The **raio()[, 3]** is the column with values to be color scaled. Then I try:

```
 observe({
         leaflet::leafletProxy("bbmap", data = raio) %>% 
         leaflet::clearShapes() %>%
         leaflet::addPolylines(data = poliMG$geom, weight = 0.5, color = "black") %>%
         leaflet::addPolygons(data = teste,
                              weight = 0.3,
                              opacity = 2,
                              color = "black",
                              fillColor =  ~pal()
                              )
}
)
```

The result is:

```
Warning: Error in UseMethod: metod not appliable to 'metaData' aplied to a object of class "c('sfc_MULTIPOLYGON', 'sfc')"
```

When I do not use the fillColor, the app runs perfectly but with no color scaled.
Please, need some help here.